# FormAuthentication not works when html5 Appcache enable in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, browser-cache, html5-appcache

In My Mvc application i have enable Html5 Appcache which cache only js,css and images. The problem is when enabling the appcache my FormaAthentication fails. After disabling  it's works fine. I don't know why it is happening.Please give me a solution for resolving this.

Comment: is this a single page app?